# How to quantify the difference of each value with respect to the median of a list of values

Tags: r, correlation, median

I have a list of 7 numbers in the range [0-1]. I have a median of all of them. I would like to quantify how much different each number is from the median. 
Probably a rather basic question, but how can I measure this?

```
list <-c(0.934, 0.003, 0.006, 0.761, 0.654, 0.765, 0.321)

Median: 0.654. 

0.934-0.654 =0.28     
0.003-0.654=-0.651
```

What I would like to know is: is 0.934 significantly different from the median value? the same for the other numbers.

Comment: @ssdecontrol The question was edited out from under your otherwise useful guidance.

Comment: Sorry..now my problem is explained in a better way I suppose.

Comment: @ssde Sorry about that--I'll delete my comment and perhaps you might want to do the same with yours, now that it is outdated and potentially confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if a statistical test can be performed on a single realization of a random variable. Being random, it can take any value within its range. Let say they are from the normal distribution, one can say 0.934 is 0.28 away from the median (also mean in this case) but I don't think it is possible to say whether 0.28 is significant or not.

Statistical tests are largely depends on the central limit theorem and they focus on sample statistic rather than individual realizations.